# the database file cannot be found. check the path to the database. data source in windows phone 7

Tags: database, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i have created the data base in windows phone 7 and it works me fine

after rebuild the application it says that

> The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database. [ Data Source = \Applications\Data\6157CB94-31D3-4E6F-BFC3-78BE1549C10A\Data\IsolatedStore\amit.sdf ]

my code for db string is

```
` private const string Con_String = @"isostore:/amit.sdf";`
```

how to solve this pls give me any suggestion to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked this sample  [How to create a basic local database app for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202876%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)?

they use this path for create the db

```
//Specify the connection string as a static, used in main page and app.xaml.
public static string DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/ToDo.sdf";
```

and also don't forget to check if the db exists

```
//Create the database if it does not exist.
using (ToDoDataContext db = new ToDoDataContext(ToDoDataContext.DBConnectionString))
{
   if (db.DatabaseExists() == false)
   {
      //Create the database
      db.CreateDatabase();
    }
 }
```

Comment: thanks i forget to add create the database if it does not exist , now it works me fine thanks